# QModbusDataUnit + float

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Добрый день! 
Подскажие как получить float значения? Код для чтения регистров.

```
  if(!modbusDevice)
        return;

    statusBar()->clearMessage();

    QVector<quint16> mm;
    mm.append(1);
    mm.append(2);
    mm.append(3);
    mm.append(4);
    mm.append(5);
    mm.append(6);

    QModbusDataUnit readUnit(QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters, 4, mm);


    if(auto *reply = modbusDevice->sendReadRequest(readUnit, 1)){
        if(!reply->isFinished())
            connect(reply, &QModbusReply::finished, this, &MainWindow::ReadyRead);
        else
            delete reply;
    }else {
        ui->textEdit->append(modbusDevice->errorString());
    }
```

Integer считывает отлично, а вот float показывает странные числа. 
Например: В регистре число 4.12, но считываем его как 2 регистра со значениями 55050 и 16515. Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что размер регистра, как я понял, составляет 2 байта (`quint16`), а `float` хранится в 4-х байтах. Можно преобразовать 2 регистра `quint16` в `float`:

```
QVector<quint16> mm;
mm.push_back(55050);
mm.push_back(16515);

quint16 valBuf[2] = { mm[0], mm[1] };
float result = *(float*)valBuf;
```

Или же вычитывать регистры как `quint32` (`QVector<quint32> mm;`) и тогда:

```
float result = *(float*)&mm[0];
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли! Но, не могли вы объяснить что происходит, каким образом из 55050 и 16515, получаем 4.12?